# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './foo/foo.scss' in

Tags: webpack, sass

I cannot get to import my scss file into my tsx file. I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./wwwroot/clientapp/components/technology/technology.tsx
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './technology/technology.scss' in 'C:\Repo\hobby\01.Code\Core\wwwroot\clientapp\components\technology'
> @ ./wwwroot/clientapp/components/technology/technology.tsx 3:0-38
> @ ./wwwroot/clientapp/app.tsx
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! asp.net@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the asp.net@1.0.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

My webpack:

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                {
                    loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
                    options: {
                        namedexport: true,
                        camelcase: true,
                        modules: true
                    }
                },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ]
        },
```

Added a declartion file under a new folder typings:

```
declare module '*.css' {
    const content: { [className: string]: string; };
    export default content;
}
declare module '*.scss' {
    const content: { [className: string]: string; };
    export default content;
}
```

and then importing:

```
import './foo/foo.scss';
```

When I do `npm run build` I get the error described above.

Comment: where is `./technology/technology.scss` import?
Where technology.scss is located relatively to the file that imports it?

Comment: yes it is located relative to import. It is correct since the auto complete did show the file paths

Comment: can you please share the complete error?

Comment: updated the full error message. Somehow the compiler is not generating declaration scss files

Comment: @AdiLavi, some IDE's autocomplete doesn't always work correctly. I've had issue in the past with VSCode the autocomplete import statement can be wrong. I wouldn't rely on to always be 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message if you change the import from

```
'./technology/technology.scss'
```

to

```
'./technology.scss'
```

its suppose to work, can you check please?

Comment: Silly me, yes it works. Thanks. But it still did not generate d.scss file, do you know why? But the styling is there and works.

Comment: Not sure I follow, why would you want it to generate d.scss file? What would be the content of this file?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but as to what I read is that `technology.scss.d.ts` should be generated so that the style can be imported into typescript file. Since ts only understands `.ts` and `.tsx` imports.

Comment: sorry I don't know anything about that